remove the white background in header on createBottomTabNavigator
when i use border radios i got white background and cannot find the issue , can you please help me find the relevant error ?

code :
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { View, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { useTheme } from "../../context/ThemeContext";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const platform = getPlatfrom();

const TabNavigator = () => {
  const { currentTheme, theme } = useTheme();

  const screenOptions = ({ route }) => ({
    headerBackground: () => (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          shadowColor: "transparent", // this covers iOS
          elevation: 0, // this covers Android
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: currentTheme.primary,
          borderRadius: 20,
        }}
      />
    ), // Ensure the entire header is covered with the background color
    headerTintColor: currentTheme.background, // Customize the text color of the header

    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: "bold", // Customize the font weight of the header title
    },
  });

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={SHome}
        options={{
          title: "Home", // Customize the title of the screen
          headerRight: () => (
            <Ionicons
              name="home"
              size={24}
              color={currentTheme.background}
              style={{ marginRight: 15 }}
            />
          ), // Customize the right header icon
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="View"
        component={SHome}
        options={{
          title: "View", // Customize the title of the screen
          headerRight: () => (
            <MaterialIcons
              name="view-kanban"
              size={24}
              color={currentTheme.background}
              style={{ marginRight: 15 }}
            />
          ), // Customize the right header icon
        }}
      />

    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
export default TabNavigator;

i try to change the background of safe area view but not luck , i want 1 single color for the header and the body and keep the rounded edge's

Please share your theme.
